# a4j:support is calling the action method and it is not giving any error in jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3

Tags: jsf, richfaces

My fragment is as follows:

```
<h:form id="formforautomanualmatch">

        <a4j:support id="manualMatchProductivityHigh" ajaxSingle="true"
                     style="visibility: hidden;height:0; width:0 " event="onchanged"
                     onbeforedomupdate="destroyDropdownStyle()"
                     oncomplete="drawHighChart(ManualMatchProductivity,#{automanualmatchbean.jsonDataProductivity})"
                     action="#{automanualmatchbean.chartData}"
                     reRender="ManualMatchProductivity">
        </a4j:support>

        <h:inputText id="jsonData"
                     value="#{automanualmatchbean.jsonDataProductivity}" />
        <rich:panel id="ManualMatchProductivity"
                    bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
            <h:inputText id="dateRanges" value="#{bean.selectedRange}" />
            <h:inputText id="fromDate"
                         value="#{automanualmatchbean.selectedStartDate}" />
            <h:inputText id="toDate" value="#{bean.to_date}" />
            <h:inputText id="dataBy" value="#{bean.dataByValue}" />
        </rich:panel>
</h:form>
```

My action method is not getting called. I am not able to figure out what is the problem. I think it should call `getChartdata` method from the bean class. But due to some reason it is not calling that method. When I am using this bean into another XHTML page's action, then it is calling that method.

My bean class is as follows:

```
@Controller("automanualmatchbean")
public class AutoManualMatchBean {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private Date selectedStartDate;
    private Date selectedEndDate;
    private String selectedDataBy;
    private JSONArray jsonDataProductivity=new JSONArray();
    private String jsonDataRuleEffec = "{}";
    private String jsonDataRuleQuality = "{}";
    private String jsonDataRecDistribution = "{}";

    @Autowired
    AutoManualMatchImpl autoManualMatchImpl;

    // all standard getters and setters

    public void getChartData() {
        // Loading the Details of the Chart
        jsonDataProductivity.add("{12}");
        System.out.println("Inside AutoManualMatchBean getChartData");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

        String matchType = (String) map.get("matchType");
        String pFromDate = (String) map.get("parentFromDate");
        String ptoDate = (String) map.get("parentToDate");
        String pDataType = (String) map.get("parentDataBy");

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        try {
            selectedStartDate = formatter.parse(pFromDate);
            selectedEndDate = formatter.parse(ptoDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("Error while parsing the date in getChartData");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("AutoManualMatchBean --> Start getChartData");

        jsonDataProductivity = autoManualMatchImpl.getChartDataProductivity(
            matchType, pFromDate, ptoDate, pDataType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's supposed to work. Have you tried `action="#{automanualmatchbean.getChartData()}"` instead? (However you shouldn't put business logic in a getter to begin with)

Comment: Yes i had tried that. But still it is not working.

Comment: I just noticed the a4j:support is inside a form and not an input component, how do you want it to work?

Comment: I wanted this to be executed as soon as the page is loaded in the browser, it should trigger the action method inside the bean and it should reRender the id of the panel that is specified..

Comment: Why not use `@PostConstruct` then? You have it set to execute when the form's onchange event fires but there is no such event.